# smart contract function call error

Tags: smart-contract, error, flipper

I am deploying flipper ink! smart contract to shibuya, but when I tried to read the value using `get()` I am getting this error:

> { Err: { Module: { index: 70 error: 0x02000000 } } }

I also tried deploying it to rococo and getting similar error:

> { Err: { Module: { index: 40 error: 0x02000000 } } }

any idea what is the error and why ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is because of Shibuya has updated to Weights v2.

If you are getting this error on polkadot.js we are working on a fix for it https://github.com/polkadot-js/apps/pull/8538.

If you are getting this from your code you can fix like this:

Weights v2 requires refTime and proofSize. refTime is equal to v1 weight.

Both values can be fetched by sending the txn as a query and using the gasRequired value.

```typescript
const { gasRequired, result, output } = await contract.query.flip(
  address,
  {
    gasLimit: api.registry.createType('WeightV2', {
      refTime,
      proofSize,
    }) as WeightV2,
    storageDepositLimit,
  }
)

const gasLimit = api.registry.createType('WeightV2', gasRequired) as WeightV2

// Send the transaction, like elsewhere this is a normal extrinsic
// with the same rules as applied in the API (As with the read example,
// additional params, if required can follow)
await contract.tx
  .flip({
    gasLimit: gasLimit,
    storageDepositLimit
  })
  .signAndSend(account, async (res) => {
    if (res.status.isInBlock) {
      console.log('in a block')
    } else if (res.status.isFinalized) {
      console.log('finalized')
    }
  })
```

Comment: What should the initial values of `refTime` and `proofSize` be? Whenever I run a query like this I get `{ refTime: '0', proofSize: '0' }` returned as `gasRequired`.

Comment: any call with `{ value: 0, gasLimit: -1 }` fails after deploying with Shibuya, any way to fix this?

Answer (score 4):

It looks like the same issue still occurs in 2023, moreover I realised that now interacting with Smart Contracts on https://polkadot.js.org/apps/ is broken as well. The only way to interact with them is by using https://contracts-ui.substrate.io/ which apparently has some kind of workaround for that WeightV2 issue. Nevertheless, as a fulfilment of the reply from Adam Wierzbicki, you need to add following parts to make your code work.

First of all import these at the top of the code block

```typescript
import { BN, BN_ONE } from "@polkadot/util";
import type { WeightV2 } from '@polkadot/types/interfaces'
```

Somewhere below define two new variables

```typescript
const MAX_CALL_WEIGHT = new BN(5_000_000_000_000).isub(BN_ONE);
const PROOFSIZE = new BN(1_000_000);
```

Execute query on the given function to retrieve the required gas limit

```typescript
const storageDepositLimit = null;

const { gasRequired } = await contract.query.flip(
  account.address,
  {
    gasLimit: api?.registry.createType('WeightV2', {
      refTime: MAX_CALL_WEIGHT,
      proofSize: PROOFSIZE,
    }) as WeightV2,
    storageDepositLimit,
  }
);
```

Define the gas limit variable and execute transaction call

```typescript
const gasLimit = api?.registry.createType('WeightV2', gasRequired) as WeightV2
   
await contract.tx
  .flip({
    gasLimit,
    storageDepositLimit
  })
  .signAndSend(alice, async (res) => {
    if (res.status.isInBlock) {
      console.log('in a block')
    } else if (res.status.isFinalized) {
      console.log('finalized')
    }
  });
```

If you need to only read some data from the Smart contract you can query it like in the code block below

```typescript
const { result, output } = await contract.query.get(
  alice.address,
  {
    gasLimit: api?.registry.createType('WeightV2', {
      refTime: MAX_CALL_WEIGHT,
      proofSize: PROOFSIZE,
    }) as WeightV2,
    storageDepositLimit,
  }
);
   
// The actual result from RPC as `ContractExecResult`
console.log(result.toHuman());
    
// check if the call was successful
if (result.isOk) {
  // output the return value
  console.log("Success", output?.toHuman());
} else {
  console.error("Error", result.asErr);
}
```

Comment: This worked like a charm! Thank you!

Comment: My pleasure to help :) As far as I know the issue has been already addressed in the Polkadot.js dashboard, so probably they should release new version of library as well.