# "new CodePromise" now throws an error [ Issue of Weight V2]

Tags: polkadot-js, astar

- I implemented this sample(https://github.com/realtakahashi/polkadot_js_examples) about 3 months ago
- This sample works on astar-collator v4.33.0, but does not work on v4.39.0
- I got an error when "new CodePromise" was executed.
- Has the way you use CodePromise changed with recent updates?
- If anyone knows, please let me know.

#Error Info

```
Unhandled Runtime Error
Error: Your runtime does not expose the api.call.contractsApi.call runtime interfaces
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- This issue causes by Wheigt V2.
- Same issue was already exists.
- Refer to....

[smart contract function call error](https://substrate.stackexchange.com/questions/6401/smart-contract-function-call-error)