# What's the difference between `paymentInfo` and `gasRequired`?

Tags: polkadot-js, contracts, gas

In polkadotJS there are **two** ways of getting gas estimates (specifically `WeightV2`) before you send a contract transaction.

The **first** uses `query` and returns a `gasRequired` value in the result.

```
    const extrinsic = contract.query[message.method](address, initialOptions, ...encodedArgs)
    const response = await extrinsic
    if (response.result.isOk) {
        // create a new set of options using gasRequired and storageDeposit
        let options = getOptions(this.api, message.isMutating, value, response.gasRequired, response.storageDeposit)
```

The **second** uses `tx` and takes a value from `paymentInfo`

```
        // options here uses the gasRequired from the initial query as the gasLimit
        const extrinsicTx = contract.tx[message.method](options, ...encodedArgs)
        const paymentInfo = await extrinsicTx.paymentInfo(address)
```

`paymentInfo` always gives a higher `refTime` value than `gasRequired`.

```
gasRequired 8,827,448,665
paymentInfo 9,536,660,665
```

Using the value from `gasRequired` causes `OutOfGas` errors when batching transactions. Using the value from `paymentInfo` causes the batched transactions to succeed.

Why are there two different ways of getting gas estimates and why do they differ in value?

Note: [This answer](https://substrate.stackexchange.com/questions/7100/how-to-estimate-gas-for-ink-contracts-transactions-for-weights-v2) suggests that the contract state being modified between transactions could be the reason for the difference in gas and to increase gas by 1%. However, the difference between `gasRequired` refTime and `paymentInfo` refTime is ~8%.

Comment: if you just perform a single contracts call, and not a batch transaction, is the gasRequired enough (it should be).

Comment: Also if you could write js snippets that I could actually use to repro in the polkadot js app, this might help me investigate that further.

Answer (score 2):

Are your calls failing with `OutOfGas` when submitted individually or only when batched?

The difference may be due to the different runtime apis called under the hood:

- `transactionPaymentApi.queryInfo` for `tx.paymentInfo`
- `contractsApi.call` for `contract.query`

There may be extra costs for batching that are not estimated by `contractsApi`