# Problem deploying smart contract on rococo

Tags: polkadot-js, smart-contract, transactions, error

I have been following the public documentation of polkadot API to deploy contract: https://polkadot.js.org/docs/api-contract/start/code

but I'm getting error `Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: code.tx.new is not a function`

here is my script:

```sh
import { ApiPromise, WsProvider } from "@polkadot/api";
import { CodePromise, ContractPromise } from "@polkadot/api-contract";
import { Keyring } from "@polkadot/keyring";

export const deployContract= async (wasm,abi,providerURL ="wss://rococo-contracts-rpc.polkadot.io",endowment=123456789,gasLimit=5000000n)=>{
    if(!wasm || !abi) {alert('wasm or abi not provided!'); return;}

    const provider = new WsProvider(providerURL);
    const api = await ApiPromise.create({ provider });
    const code = new CodePromise(api, abi, wasm);
    const keyring = new Keyring({ type: "sr25519" });
    const dataJsonAccount = {THIS_IS_JUST_PLACEHOLDER} 
    const tx = code.tx.new({gasLimit,storageDepositLimit:null})
    let address;
    const account = keyring.addFromJson(dataJsonAccount);
    account.decodePkcs8('THIS_IS_JUST_PLACEHOLDER');

    try{
      const unsub = await tx.signAndSend(account, ({ contract, status }) => {
        if (status.isInBlock || status.isFinalized) {
          address = contract.address.toString();
          console.info(address)
          unsub();
        }
      });
  }

  catch(e){
    console.info(e);
  }
```

Later I tried to print what is `code.tx` and I got result that there is a only `construct` function.

so I used that one like this:

```sh
          const tx = code.tx.construct({gasLimit,storageDepositLimit:null})
```

and it kinda worked, but I'm never getting my contract deployed for some reason.
I'm getting this error:

```sh
          TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'address')
```

which means contract here:

```
          address = contract.address.toString();
```

is never deployed.

I also tried using Contracts-UI to deploy contract manually(by just uploading .contract, and it works.

What I'm missing, what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 3):

Actually, this: [smart contract function call error](https://substrate.stackexchange.com/questions/6401/smart-contract-function-call-error) solved my question.

It seems that Polkadot documentation is not up to date.