# How do set the appropriate refTime and proofSize when create asMulti?

Tags: ink, weight, multisig, gas

We had a big problem after upgrading weight -> weight v2.

I understood that weight v2 uses refTime and proofSize.
However, I wonder if there is a way to properly look up these two values.

We are using sidecar(send Tx) and tx-wrapper-core(sign Tx).

And I saw this [post](https://substrate.stackexchange.com/questions/6401/smart-contract-function-call-error/6402#6402). Is this code also available in multisig, not contract?

give thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- You can create your `asMulti` call with some default values for `reftime` and `proofsize`.
- An example would be to set at your new weight the same `RefTime` as found in your old weight and for `proofsize` a default value like `0`.
- Then use the corresponding runtime call to get a more accurate estimation of these parameters.
- An example can be found in the [multisig](https://github.com/paritytech/txwrapper-core/blob/main/packages/txwrapper-examples/multisig/src/multisig.ts) example of txwrapper-core.
- There, the `maxweight` in the `asMulti` is set to [these values](https://github.com/paritytech/txwrapper-core/blob/ff771e39c9966a87ad460ef0c67ed67f10601726/packages/txwrapper-examples/multisig/src/multisig.ts#L507).
- We can then copy the serialized signed tx (in the txwrapper example is called `txAsMulti`) that is printed and use the runtime call `queryInfo` from `TransactionPaymentApi` to get more accurate estimation for `reftime` and `proofsize`.

  - we can call this either from [pjs-apps link](https://polkadot.js.org/apps/?rpc=wss%3A%2F%2Fdot-rpc.stakeworld.io#/runtime)
  - or sidecar's `/transaction/fee-estimate` endpoint which uses the same [call](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate-api-sidecar/blob/f486aa94bd86b21d460aaf2285dda1c535cfb969/src/services/transaction/TransactionFeeEstimateService.ts#L42)

For the `asMulti` call of this txwrapper example, I use the below curl command

```
curl -X 'POST' \
  'http://127.0.0.1:8080/transaction/fee-estimate' \
  -H 'accept: application/json' \
  -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
  -d '{
  "tx": "0x950384008eaf04151687736326c9fea17e25fc5287613693c912909cb226aa4794f26a480160cf28a7cdac2e4a10883a22bf40cf764417418591fc2bd72800340c6f7edd774d7f1eb158ab004f0e920db9dabbe041c081585c18610f39d4cc274b371df187150000001e0102000890b5ab205c6974c9ea841be688864633dc9ca8a357843eeacf2314649965fe22d43593c715fdd31c61141abd04a99fd6822c8558854ccde39a5684e7a56da27d010200000003000000050300e659a7a1628cdd93febc04a4e0646ea20e9f5f0ce097d9a05290d4a9e054df4e0f00c029f73d54050280969800"
}'
```

and the result I will receive (while connected to Polkadot)

```
{"weight":{"refTime":"886228054","proofSize":"6811"},"class":"Normal","partialFee":"249232647"}%
```

which is the same result that I get from pjs apps.

Last, a great resource to get more information on weights is the [Deep Dive in Weights](https://youtu.be/iM-M74kM1cU?si=gcvvSEUj9Vk1h7dE) which I absolutely recommend.