# What are the best refTime and proofSize for making AsMultiTx?

Tags: weight, fee

- Our's Environment

  - Use sidecar (v17.0.0)
  - Use Tx-wrapper-core (v7.0.1) https://github.com/paritytech/txwrapper-core
  - Polkadot node v1.0.0
  - Use Westend(testnet) and Polkadot(mainnet)

Since being updated from weightV1 to weightV2,

we are looking for proper values of 'refTime' and 'proofSize' for AsMulti transaction.

Recently, a few simple tests have confirmed that the values below are operating normally. (on the Testnet!)

- refTime:  640000000
- proofSize : 13622

1. Can I keep the above values fixed and continue to use them?
2. Do you have an appropriate value to recommend?

Our goal is to send transactions without problems even in the worst-case scenario.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

first of all, sorry for the lack of docs, even though that's not our area I know how frustrating is to turn to the docs for help and not finding anything.

Now onto your questions:

1. You can use those values as long as the call remains the same, remember that the actual weight varies a little between calls, so be sure to give it a little slack to account for those variations.
2. We don't really recommend anything about the weights, it really depends on the specifics of the call, sorry.

The best approach is to make some dry runs to estimate an upper bound of the weight of your specific calls and use that, keeping in mind that unused allocated weight would be refunded but at the same time that the weight you state is used to determine block allocation, so if your allocated weight is too little the call fails, but if its too large it could take a lot of time to find a block that will incorporate your call.

You can refer to this [SE](https://substrate.stackexchange.com/a/10271/4314) answer for more in depth info.